# ExecuteReaderAsync and Autofac

Tags: c#, oracle, autofac

I have created an **OracleUnitOfWork** and **Repository** class like this:

```
public class OracleUnitOfWork : IOracleUnitOfWork
{
    // Private properties
    private readonly OracleConnection _connection;
    private readonly OracleCommand _command;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _repositories;
    private Object thisLock = new Object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config">The Cormar config class</param>
    public OracleUnitOfWork(CormarConfig config)
    {

        // Create instances for our private properties
        this._repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        this._connection = new OracleConnection(config.ConnectionString);
        this._command = new OracleCommand
        {
            Connection = this._connection,
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            BindByName = true
        };

        // Open our connection
        this._connection.Open();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the entity repository
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The entity model</typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class, new()
    {

        // Lock the thread so we can't execute at the same time
        lock (thisLock)
        {

            // If our repositories have a matching repository, return it
            if (_repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)))
                return _repositories[typeof(T)] as IRepository<T>;

            // Create a new repository for our entity
            var repository = new Repository<T>(this._command);

            // Add to our list of repositories
            _repositories.Add(typeof(T), repository);

            // Return our repository
            return repository;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes of any attached resources
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">A boolean indicating whether the object is being disposed</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {

        // If we are disposing
        if (disposing)
        {

            // Close our connection
            this._connection.Close();
            this._connection.Dispose();
            this._command.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    // private properties
    private readonly OracleCommand _command;
    private Object thisLock = new Object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command"></param>
    public Repository(OracleCommand command)
    {
        this._command = command;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the datareader for the stored procedure
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="storedProcedureName">The name of the SPROC to execute</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">The parameters needed for the SPROC</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(string storedProcedureName, IList<OracleParameter> parameters = null)
    {

        // Set up our command
        this.InitiateCommand(storedProcedureName, parameters.ToArray());

        // Return our data reader
        return await this._command.ExecuteReaderAsync();            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create, updates or deletes an entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="storedProcedureName">The name of the SPROC to execute</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">The parameters needed for the SPROC</param>
    public async Task CreateUpdateOrDeleteAsync(string storedProcedureName, IList<OracleParameter> parameters = null)
    {

        // Set up our command
        this.InitiateCommand(storedProcedureName, parameters.ToArray());

        // Execute our command
        await this._command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Intiates the command object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="storedProcedureName">The name of the SPROC to execute</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">An array of parameters</param>
    private void InitiateCommand(string storedProcedureName, OracleParameter[] parameters)
    {

        // Lock the thread so we can't execute at the same time
        lock (thisLock)
        {

            // Set up the command object
            this._command.CommandTimeout = 1800;
            this._command.FetchSize = 1000;
            this._command.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
            this._command.Parameters.Clear();

            // If we have any parameters
            if (parameters != null)
            {

                // Assign each parameter to the command object
                this._command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my AutoFac module, I register the **OracleUnitOfWork** as a single instance like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<OracleUnitOfWork>().As<IOracleUnitOfWork>().SingleInstance();
```

For most queries, this is fine, but I seem to have a problem when trying to execute multiple queries simultaneously. It errors out on the **ExecuteReaderAsync** method in my repository and states:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Sometimes I even get this error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

But I can't figure out how to fix the issue.
Prior to this I was getting issues with the **GetRepository** method, but when I added locking that fixed the issue. I can't do that to **ExecuteReaderAsync** method because it will no longer be asynchronous and I need it to be.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Kushan` is right about `OracleConnection` not being thread safe. If you really need to execute multiple queries in the same time and you are not affected by the overhead, you can remove `SingleInstance()` and allow multiple instances to be built.

This way, each of your threads can obtain a new instance of `OracleUnitOfWork` and do its work independently (fetch data, perform changes, persist changes).

Answer (score 2):

> For most queries, this is fine, but I seem to have a problem when
>   trying to execute multiple queries simultaneously.

You have a race condition, you're trying to access the same references across multiple threads and getting "spooky" behaviour.

You can't pass a mutable singleton across multiple threads like that, it will break. Either bite the bullet and use a a [_lock](https://www.dotnetperls.com/lock) or rethink your approach (i.e. Don't use a singleton).

Just remember, locks will kill your multi-threaded performance if not used correctly.